# Is there any particular speed of reading a code by the compiler?

Tags: c, performance

I have noticed that 10(^7) or 10 000 000 increment is equal to 10 seconds in my environment.
Here is an example of custom function that works for me that wastes x seconds before the next line:

```
void pause(unsigned short seconds)
{
    int f;
    unsigned long long deltaTime = seconds*10000000;

    for(f=0; f<deltaTime; f++);
}
```

with this function you can request specific amount of seconds for "pause".
However.. i am not sure if thats even correct. Maybe the speed of listening the code depends from the compiller or the processor.. or both?

Comment: Yes, there is a particular speed, but not of the compiler.  It is called the CPU Clock speed, and many modern chips are typically around 3GHz.   The cycles will be divided among functions of the Operating System and other programs that are also running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things wrong here:

- In most compilers, if you enable optimizations (`-O`), it'll totally remove this code realizing it does nothing.
- the speed of the loop is determined by compiler, processor, system load, and many other aspects
- There's already a `sleep` function.

Comment: Yeah i know about sleep. But i was curious about the speed in general.
And anyway.. in my case, this function works though. Also the compiler im using is really old. It has no optimization feature.

Comment: Run your code on a faster/slower PC and you'll get different results. It's not the way to go.

Comment: Yes, i just haven't program in another compilers so i wouldn't know. There are a lot of people actually curious about the speed of listening the lines....

Comment: If you really want accurate "pause" without using sleep, then use a tight loop around `gettimeofday` and check the resulting `tv_sec`.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the DOS games in the 90's which ran at different speeds depending on the processor.

Comment: @Martin: and, if they synced to the screen refresh, on different speeds in Europe (50Hz) and the US (60Hz). Shoot-em-up's were 16% more difficult!